How to shutdown Flask server and restart it with a different IP from the same Python script?
Here is the Flask setup for the problem.
import threading
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/restart', methods=['GET'])
def restart():
    shutdown() # How do I shutdown the Flask server?
    flask_thread.join()
    flask_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_flask, args=(new_IP,))
    flask_thread.start()
    return 'Hello again, World!'

def start_flask(ip):
    app.run(host=ip)

old_IP = '123.123.123.123'
new_IP = '234.234.234.234'

flask_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_flask, args=(old_IP,))
flask_thread.start()

How do I shutdown the Flask server, and restart it with a different IP?

Hello, sorry, may I get a bit more details. What goal are you trying to achieve by changing IP of the flask app?

I don't know, it's a client request

Maybe what you are trying to achive is a server operation rather than a flask function. Your previous question was also aligning with that. Start the flask app with a bash script, kill the process when necessary and start another process. I'm no expert in these, but a process manager such as supervisor or systemd should be responsible for these actions, restarting in case of failure etc..

sorry, but I guess there might be misunderstanding of where the server IP address gets assigned.
Simplifying every computer usually has three IP addresses:

Your computer loopback address (127.x.x.x)
Your private network IP address, for example your employee has it's own private network which you are a part of (10.x.x.x or 192.x.x.x). If your accessing internet from home then your wi-fi router is hiddenly creating this private network for you.
Global internet public IP Address (any four number XXX.XXX.XXX.XX that weren't included in two previous cases)

So how IP addresses are assigned:

loopback IP address doesn't do anything, it is always redirecting back to your computer. There is no need to assign it. Usually instead of using loopback address in full form like http://127.x.x.x you may simply use http://localhost.
internal network private IP address is used to find computers in the private network. This IP addresses are assigned by network routers / network administrators. Neither Flask nor python can influence the choice of an IP address in this case.
Global internet public IP address is assigned by your internet provider. Not by Flask or python. Usually you can't ask provider to change the IP assigned to you (most probably it is very bureaucratic procedure). However you can hide your IP address using VPN or proxies. If the IP address is hidden by the proxy you may say that the IP address was changed, because any external site will only see VPN or proxy IP and not your server public IP address.
Global public IP address might be assigned by the hosting cloud provider. If the flask app is hosted on the cloud you can issue and reassign new IP address using the cloud API. Just as an example you can use AWS API to periodically change IP address (in AWS it is called Elastic IP) of the instance that hosts the flask app (an EC2 instance). However based on your question I can't be sure that this is the scope of your task.

DNS records
Another topic that might be related to your question is editing DNS records. So basically DNS record is a sitename, for example hostname "https://spokentutor.com" has several DNS records associated with it (check them here: https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=spokentutor.com&rtype=ALL&dns=google). One of the records is an A record which stores site IP address 76.76.21.21. So when user wants to access the hostname his browser (Firefox/Chrome/Safari) will request the DNS records and take the IP address listed in the A record. So basically if the site is hosted with the name "http://mylongsite.org" you can change it's IP address by editing DNS record. However obviously if you've changed the server IP address this means that the flask server was copied and started on a second computer that has different public IP address.
And what the Flask has to do with all of this?
Flask indeed has an option to set host IP addresses when running the app app.run(host='XX.XX.XX.XX'). However this option doesn't change your IP address neither locally, nor in a private network, nor global public IP address. What this option does is controlling who sees the app:

only your computer (host = 'localhost');
your private network (host='10.x.x.x');
everyone in the internet (host='0.0.0.0'). 

You can prove this by getting your IP from https://www.whatismyip.com/ (create flask method that downloads this page and extracts an IP address) with different values of host attribute. So values in the host attribute not affecting the flask server/computer IP address.
To sum up:
Back to your question. To better understand the situation it would be good to know what IP are you trying to change:

your server public IP address (the IP address exposed to the internet);
your server private IP address (your app exist mainly in the private network and for some reason you'd like to periodically change the private IP);

Are you trying to rotate IP for incoming or outgoing requests:

any internet user -> connects to server public IP -> flask app;
flask app -> connects to internet via server public IP -> any site in the internet;

Pls comment and tell me if this information make sense. Sorry for such a long post.

Thanks for the helpful information. I suppose the client needs a way to change from one private network address to another. I did not know anything about IP addresses, which seems to be have caused confusion.

thx for the reply. In such case you should connect with the client network administrator and ask him how best to do this. Maybe you need to find some more details and rephrase the question. And once again unfortunately Flask library won't help to solve your problem.

One may use os.execl to achieve this goal:
ip_addr.py
IP = '123.123.123.123'

app.py
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask

from ip_addr import ip

new_IP = '0.0.0.0'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/restart', methods=['GET'])
def restart():
    with open('IP.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'ip = "{new_IP}"\n')
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, sys.argv[0])

app.run(host=ip)

And the server would restart with the designated new IP upon receiving the request.

This changes the bind address, not the external server ip that clients would use to access flask. This also seems to be starting a brand new flask server rather than restarting the current one
